# cmake install() behaviour? Why does the binary look in PWD if this directive is given

Tags: linux, installation, shared-libraries, elf, rpath

I'm searching for clarification on the behaviour of library search paths on linux binaries when using the install directive in cmake.

For context and to simplify, we have a binary and a library that are located in the same directory.

We've been narrowing down some unusual behaviour with the program that works in some environments, and not in others.  Our problems all began when we added the following line to our CMAKE file:

```
set(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH TRUE)
```

After adding this line, the program no longer worked, and we saw this error:

```
binaryfile: error while loading shared libraries: mylibrary.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

We ended up narrowing the problem down to the inclusion of the install command, which I'm assuming is effectively undone by the SKIP_RPATH addition.

After a lot of mucking around to diagnose why the code worked with and without the RPATH setting, we discovered what's causing the issue, but I don't understand why this can happen, based on the rpath in the binary.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.15)
project (binaryfile)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/runtime")
link_directories (${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/../mylibrary)
link_libraries(mylibrary)
add_executable(binaryfile program.cpp)
# The following line allows the binary to find mylibrary in the same directory
install (TARGETS binaryfile DESTINATION bin)
```

After building, and *moving* the .so file from its build location to the same folder as the binary, this is the output of ldd and readelf

On the binary build with install ...

```
readelf -d binaryfile
Dynamic section at offset 0xdc0 contains 30 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libmylibrary.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/dev/rpath-test/program/../mylibrary:]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x4004b8
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x400654
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x600db0
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x600db8
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000004 (HASH)               0x400298
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x4002c8
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x400380
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x4002f0
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              191 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x601000
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x4004a0
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x400470
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             48 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x400450
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x400440
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0


ldd binaryfile
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff6099e000)
    libmylibrary.so (0x00007fdff4d91000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdff4a07000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdff46cf000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fdff44b7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdff40fd000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdff4f93000)
```

On the binary build without install ...

```
readelf -d binaryfile
Dynamic section at offset 0xdc0 contains 30 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libmylibrary.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/dev/rpath-test/program/../mylibrary]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x4004b8
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x400654
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x600db0
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x600db8
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000004 (HASH)               0x400298
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x4002c8
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x400380
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x4002f0
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              190 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x601000
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x4004a0
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x400470
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             48 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x400450
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x40043e
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0

ldd binaryfile
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffecd3b5000)
        libmylibrary.so => not found
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7d9179f000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7d91467000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7d9124f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7d90e95000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7d91b29000)
```

If mylibrary.so exists in /home/dev/rpath-test/mylibrary then both binaries work, as expected, and also report that libmylibrary.so is located in that directory.  What I'm trying to understand is what is the key that's allowing the 'install' version to find the library in the pwd.

readelf shows that there is a colon at the end of the runpath.  I'm guessing that this is significant - does it mean that an empty string is part of the runpath, and that it infers pwd?

Look forward to any insights into this.

Comment: Please show _actual_ output from `ldd`, not a reduced version of it.

Comment: Dug deeper and have new insights into the source of the problem.  I seem to have a clear view of the actual source of the issue now, but still trying to find an explanation for the behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing that this is significant

Yes.

> does it mean that an empty string is part of the runpath

Yes.

> and that it infers pwd?

Kind of: `ld-linux` will path-join each `:`-separated component of `RPATH` with the name of the library, and will try to open the resulting path.

For the `/home/dev/rpath-test/program/../mylibrary:` `RPATH`, `ld-linux` will try to open `/home/dev/rpath-test/program/../mylibrary/libmylibrary.so`, and if that fails `libmylibrary.so`.

If `libmylibrary.so` exists in the current working directory, then `ld-linux` will find it.